# How do i summon a falling command block with two different tile entity data

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

how would i add another command or setting to my falling block like making it always active and repeating [image]

Comment: Hi TD_, welcome to Arqade! I'm having trouble understanding what you want, and what you've tried so far. Can you give us some commands and screenshots of what you've tried so far and why it didn't work?

Comment: Please see [What to do before asking a minecraft-commands question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the falling block's **auto** tag to 1

```
/summon minecraft:falling_block ~ ~ ~ {BlockState:{Name:"command_block"},Time:1,TileEntityData:{Command:"say hi",auto:1}}
```

the auto tag allows the command block to run the command without receiving a redstone signal. All data values for the command block: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block#Data_values